# Is it possible to test after_create method in integration test for rolify gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, integration-testing, rolify

I am using the Rolify gem to assign users roles. It seems to work succesfully and all my tests pass without problems. However there is one test that doesn't seem to work.

Rolify offers to add `after_create`, which I added to my User model:

```
after_create :assign_mod_role

def assign_mod_role
  self.add_role :moderator, self.organization
end
```

This assigns the moderator role to each user that is created (a user is always created with an association to an organization). This works in development. The integration test I have created:

```
test "user signup" do
  log_in_as(@admin)    #@admin of @organization1
  assert_difference 'User.count' do
    post adduser_path, user: { email: "ppppp@pppp.pp",
                               username: "pppppp",
                               password: "pppppp",
                               password_confirmation: "pppppp" }
  end
  testuser = assigns(:user)
  assert_equal testuser.has_role?(:moderator, @organization1), true
end
```

The last line however fails. *Am I doing something wrong or is it not possible to test for the `after_create` method?* Perhaps the way Rolify manages roles does not allow to test for this?

---

The last three lines of the test log:

```
 [1m [36m (0.5ms) [0m   [1mSELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" [0m
 [1m [35mRole Load (0.5ms) [0m  SELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_roles"."role_id" WHERE "users_roles"."user_id" = $1 AND ((((roles.name = 'moderator') AND (roles.resource_type IS NULL) AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)) OR ((roles.name = 'moderator') AND (roles.resource_type = 'Organization') AND (roles.resource_id IS NULL)) OR ((roles.name = 'moderator') AND (roles.resource_type = 'Organization') AND (roles.resource_id = 980190962))))  [["user_id", 1067176257]]
 [1m [36m (0.5ms) [0m   [1mROLLBACK [0m
```

Comment: `after_create` is a part of [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) - it does not really have anything do with Rolify. You should use model callbacks with extreme prejudice. It's often really difficult to control when they are fired and they often don't lend well to testing. I would say that this is one case where you should not use a callback. Do it in your controller instead.

Comment: Moved it to the controller, and indeed the same test then passes. However, then on seeding the users no longer "automatically" receive the role. I tried adding `User.where(username: 'myname').add_role :moderator, Organization.where(name: 'Business name')` to the seeds file, but this produces an error: `undefined method 'add_role' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>`.

Comment: Do it in a .each loop.

Comment: But right now, I'm just trying to add the moderator role to 1 user for 1 specific organization.

Comment: Use .find_by(username: 'myname') or .where(...).first so that you get a single user record.

Comment: Perfect! If you add it as the answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`after_create` is a part of [ActiveRecord::Callbacks](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) - it does not really have anything do with Rolify. You should use model callbacks with extreme prejudice. It's often really difficult to control when they are fired and they often don't lend well to testing. I would say that this is one case where you should not use a callback. Do it in your controller instead.

If you are doing many steps creating objects than a good solution is to use service objects or factory methods on your models to keep your controllers lean.